# Deserialising JSON and child object to List<Class>

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I've checked out a few questions on StackOverflow but can't find a method that works for me.

I'm essentially trying to deserialise the following JSON into a list of my "suppressedContact" class, but I can't get it to work.

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "suppressedContact": {
    "id": 23,
    "email": "nelson.redeker@example.com",
    "optInType": "Unknown",
    "emailType": "PlainText",
    "dataFields": null,
    "status": "Unsubscribed"
  },
  "dateRemoved": "2015-09-18T15:26:25.2612537Z",
  "reason": "Unsubscribed"
  },
  {
    "suppressedContact": {
      "id": 25,
      "email": "terry.mccarthy@example.com",
      "optInType": "VerifiedDouble",
      "emailType": "Html",
      "dataFields": null,
      "status": "Unsubscribed"
    },
    "dateRemoved": "2015-02-24T13:06:42.933Z",
    "reason": "Unsubscribed"
  },
]
```

The class I am trying to deserialise into looks like this:

```
public class SuppressedRoot
{
    public Suppressedcontact suppressedContact { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateRemoved { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
}

public class Suppressedcontact
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string optInType { get; set; }
    public string emailType { get; set; }
    public object dataFields { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using this piece of code to attempt to accomplish this:

```
List<Suppressedcontact> unsubscribedContacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Suppressedcontact>>(jsonResponse);
```

This however does not work.

Any help in this would be appreciated, I'm trying to get to a stage where I can loop through all of the returned contacts and extract the email addresses.

Comment: Well it should be `List<Suppressedcontact>` not `List<Supporesscontact>` which is what you've shown when deserializing. Also `this does not work` is not helpful, what actually happens? Errors?

Comment: @Equalsk apologies, I changed the class names before posting this on to SO and miss-typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

`List<Suppressedcontact> unsubscribedContacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Supporesscontact>>(jsonResponse);`

with

`List<SuppressedRoot> unsubscribedContacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SuppressedRoot>>(jsonResponse);`